# How to launch a chrome packaged app using a URL scheme

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome packaged app that I update form time to time - when I'm creating an update I want to send email to subscribed customers with a link the that extension -that will launch it.

Anyone knows if there is a chrome url scheme i can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not possible, but there is an API proposal and an implementation being developed for a chrome-app://appid URL schema that would do pretty much what you describe.

Follow the status [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161054)

Answer (score 0):

I also want to be able to do this. It seems that one possible solution is to install both an extension and a packaged app, and have the extension register a context menu that then communicates with the app, or something similar.