# Push web api, notificationclick, how to open desktop client instead opening a new browser client

Tags: service-worker, web-push

Talking about Service Workers, when a push notifications arrives, we can handle the user click in those notifications,

for example, opening the url in a new tab of the browser if not already opened. 
But if we had a desktop web app (added to HomeScreen), how can we open it?

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    console.log('Notification click: tag ', event.notification.tag);
    event.notification.close();
    var url = 'https://youtu.be/gYMkEMCHtJ4';
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({
            type: 'window'
        })
        .then(function(windowClients) {
            for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                var client = windowClients[i];
                if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
                    return client.focus();
                }
            }
            if (clients.openWindow) {
                return clients.openWindow(url);
            }
        })
    );
});
```

In this code, clients.openWindow(url); will always open the app in the browser.

Comment: What do you mean by a "desktop web app"? (Also, for reference: on mobile, tapping on a notification will open fullscreen iff the site has been added to the homescreen once https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=541711 lands.)

Comment: Did you get to solve this  , ? I am also trying to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to launch a packaged app using the URL scheme (i.e. using `clients.openWindow()`)... yet. There is an active [proposal](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161054) to allow apps to be launched using custom URL scheme `chrome-app://APP_ID`.

A way to solve this (based on [@kzahel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18266075/599202)'s proposal) would be to use an extension with a registered context menu and then somehow tell the extensions to open the app.